# consuming standard SOAP Web Service using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio, soap, wsdl

I have consumed several wsdl services successfully, but am stuck now with this web service.
Am implementing Hotelston webservice which state :Hotelston.com API is a standard SOAP Web Service (WS) available at URL
http://www.hotelston.com/ws/HotelService?wsdl

I cant access the direct code of the webservice after i added the it as a reference in my application.

Please see the following MSDN articles for the exact details on how I added and used these web service references but still cant access it from the direct code.

[How to: Add and Remove Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7ddaa5d-4672-405b-91b3-39de65d7e3a2%28v=vs.90%29)

[How to: Call a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6e04e02-ed54-47e1-a89e-b90b5eef335d%28v=vs.90%29)

For full API documentation of wsdl file through the [link.](http://ashterelak.com/Hotelston%20API%20Specification.pdf)

Comment: What does "cant access the direct code of the webservice" mean?

Comment: I cant read the webservice from  the code behind

Answer (score 0):

If you show all files in the project and expand the service reference out, Reference.cs is empty. This is likely because there are namespace errors in HotelService.wsdl ("ax23", specifically) that is causing the t4 template to fail to generate the service code. Bottom line, it's their fault, not yours.

Comment: I have informed them and they said hundreds of their clients are using this webservice with no problem, they suggested it maybe visual studio problem. is there a tool  to test the webservice?